# R: rewrite loop with apply

Tags: r, loops

I have the following type of data set:

```
id;2011_01;2011_02;2011_03; ... ;2001_12
id01;NA;NA;123; ... ;NA
id02;188;NA;NA; ... ;NA
```

That is, each row is unique customer and each column depicts a trait for this customer from the past 10 years (each month has its own column). The thing is that I want to condense this 120 column data frame into a 10 column data frame, this because I know that almost all rows have (although the month itself can vary) have 1 or 0 observations from each year.

I've already done, one year at the time, this using a loop with a nested if-clause:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(input_data)) {
    temp_row <- input_data[i,c("2011_01","2011_02","2011_03","2011_04","2011_05","2011_06","2011_07","2011_08","2011_09","2011_10","2011_11", "2011_12")]
    loc2011 <- which(!is.na(temp_row))
    if(length(loc2011 ) > 0) {
        temp_row_2011[i,] <- temp_row[loc2011[1]] #pick the first observation if there are several
    } else {
        temp_row_2011[i,] <- NA
    }
}
```

Since my data set is quite big, and I need to perform the above loop 10 times (one for each year), this is taking way too much time. I know one is much better of using apply commands in R, so I would greatly appreciate help on this task. How could I write the whole thing (including the different years) better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you after something like this?:

```
    temp_row_2011 <- apply(input_data, 1, function(x){
        temp_row <- x[c("2011_01","2011_02","2011_03","2011_04","2011_05","2011_06","2011_07","2011_08","2011_09","2011_10","2011_11", "2011_12")]
        temp_row[!is.na(temp_row)][1]
    })
```

*If* this gives you the right output, and *if* it runs faster than your loop, then it's not necessarily due only to the fact of using an `apply()`, but also because it assigns less stuff and avoids an `if {}` `else {}`. You might be able to make it go even faster by compiling the anonymous function:

```
    reduceyear <- function(x){
        temp_row <- x[c("2011_01","2011_02","2011_03","2011_04","2011_05","2011_06","2011_07","2011_08","2011_09","2011_10","2011_11", "2011_12")]
        temp_row[!is.na(temp_row)][1]
    }
    # compile, just in case it runs faster:
    reduceyear_c <- compiler:::cmpfun(reduceyear)
    # this ought to do the same as the above.
    temp_row_2011 <- apply(input_data, 1, reduceyear_c)
```

You didn't say whether `input_data` is a `data.frame` or a `matrix`, but a matrix would be faster than the former (but only valid if `input_data` is all the same class of data).

[EDIT: full example, motivated by DWin]

```
    input_data <- matrix(ncol=24,nrow=10)
    # years and months:
    colnames(input_data) <- c(paste(2010,1:12,sep="_"),paste(2011,1:12,sep="_"))
    # some ids
    rownames(input_data) <- 1:10 
    # put in some values:
    input_data[sample(1:length(input_data),200,replace=FALSE)] <- round(runif(200,100,200))
    # make an all-NA case:
    input_data[2,1:12] <- NA

    # and here's the full deal:
    sapply(2010:2011, function(x,input_data){
        input_data_yr <- input_data[, grep(x, colnames(input_data) )] 
        apply(input_data_yr, 1, function(id){
                    id[!is.na(id)][1]
                }
        )
    }, input_data)
```

All `NA` case works. `grep()` column selection idea lifted from DWin. As in the above example, you could actually define the anonymous interior function and compile it to potentially make the thing run faster.

Comment: Thank you. I already tested your previous code and it seemed to be the building block I was looking for. I will try to automatize the whole process using this code later this weekend. Good advice.

Answer (score 1):

I built a tiny test case (for which timriffe's suggestion fails). You might attract more interest by putting up code that creates a more complete test case such as 4 quarters for 2 years and including pathological cases such as all NA's in one row of one year. I would think that instead of requiring you to write out all the year columns by name, that you ought to cycle through them with a grep() strategy:

```
  # funyear <- function to work on one year's data and return a single vector
  # my efforts keep failing on the all(NA) row by year combos
  sapply(seq("2011", "2001"), function (pat) funyear(input_data[grep(pat, names(input_data) )] )
```

Comment: thanks for checking, I updated with an example and it now works as I understood Joshua wanted.

Comment: Will post some sample data next time.